# Show series name in tooltip of Forio contour

Tags: forio-contour

I send data inside an array of objects:

```
 [{name: "x1" , data: [ ... ]}, {name: "x2" , data: [ ... ]} ... ]
```

Is it possible to show series name in the data point tooltip?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pass a tooltip formatter in the configuration, and the data object contains the series name:

```
new Contour({
    el: '.chart',
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function (d) {
            return d.series + ': ' + d.x + ', ' d.y;
        }
    }
})
.cartesian()
.line([1,2,3,3,5,6])
.tooltip()
.render();
```